# Python - writing list of lists of different lengths to file

Tags: python, list

In my code I am calculating, inside a `for` loop, a list at each iteration. For each iteration of the loop, this list will have in general a different length. I need to write ALL these lists into a file. The format needs to look like that

```
1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9

10 11 12 13 

14 15
```

where I just made a few examples: the first list has 6 elements, the second one 3, the third one 4, the last one 2.
If I call `stored_lists` my list containing all the lists, I will write something like that

```
stored_lists = []
```

and then inside a `for` loop I will `append` each of the sublist to `stored_list`.
I usually use `np.savetxt` to save 2D lists to a file. However, this time I cannot use it because if I use it I get

```
Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

How can I write `stored_lists` to a file in the format required?

*EDIT*

Actual code:

```
   stored_lists = []



   for i in range(700):

        ### here code to create new list, let's call it new_list. 
        ### This part of the code has too many references to previous code to be inserted here. 
        ### Maybe the only important part, though, is that the final operation is to sort some elements with    sorted

   stored_lists.append(new_list)
```

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to print an array as if it were a number; but since you haven't shared the code you use for writing, its hard to say ho to fix it.

Comment: Please post your actual code.